# get view tag created programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

In onCreate() method, i'm creating a TextEdit with a tag programmatically like so:

```
EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
et.setTag(field.getFieldId());
et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textbox);
et.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.noir));

parentLayout.addView(et);
```

In afterTextChanged() method , i want to retrieve that EditText tag to get the text entered by user.

I've tried this code, but i'm getting NullPointerException:

```
EditText et = (EditText) parentLayout.findViewWithTag("4249");
String strValue = et.getText().toString();
```

Can you help me please !!

Thank you.

Comment: show `logcat` and the line the `NPE` is thrown

Comment: Actually i figured out that parentLayout isn't the real parent of the EditText, it's a linearLayout created also programmatically,  so i edited my code like so: LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) parentll.findViewWithTag(field.getFieldId());
    EditText et = (EditText) layout.findViewWithTag(field.getFieldId());
    String strValue = et.getText().toString(); And i'm getting NullPointer Exception at this point: EditText et = (EditText) layout.findViewWithTag(field.getFieldId());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found a solution myself.

1) Create an EditText programmatically, set a custom TextWatcher and add the EditText to it:

```
EditText et = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                    et.setTag(field.getFieldId());
                    et.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textbox);
                    et.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.noir));
et.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(et));
```

2) Create a custom TextWatcher:

```
private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

          private EditText editText;

          private MyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
           this.editText = editText;
          }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            String strValue = this.editText.getText().toString();
            Log.d("afterTextChanged", strValue);

        }
    }
```

Hope that help other developers.